# Strunk & White badge

Tags: support, editing, badges

The silver badge "Strunk & White" -- Edited 80 posts is referred to Questions or Questions/Answer? I've edited more than 80 posts (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/56567/cornelius?tab=activity&sort=revisions), but I unearned this.

Comment: Some of those edits are for the same post, so presumably you've not got 80 independent ones.

Comment: @JosephWright Ok, I understand.

Comment: We have noticed.

Comment: Needed to say, some of the edits, despite they got approved, are very questionable. Editing a new line into a new paragraph etc. doesn't seem like a way how value is added to the site. These things are pretty minor and some of your suggested edits should have been IMHO rejected.

Comment: Related, and the main source of Werner’s answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges. In the comments over there, you’ll also find links to [data.se] queries counting your relevant edits.

Comment: Obviously the OP left us ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's difficult to tell which, but you may be short on any one of the restrictions in terms of the badge requirements. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/168244) are the edit-related moderation badge descriptions:

#### Editor

- bronze; awarded once
- Edit any post

#### Strunk & White

- silver; awarded once
- Perform a total of 80 edits between questions, answers, and tag wikis

#### Copy Editor

- gold; awarded once
- Perform a total of 500 edits between questions, answers, and tag wikis

---

The following restrictions/requirements apply:

- Edits on deleted posts do not count
- Edits to your own posts do not count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Edits to community wiki posts **do** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Tag wiki edits **do** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76916/168244))
- Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

Comment: Thanks for the details!